# disable validate_certs to false in openstack ansible deployment

Tags: ssl, ansible, openstack

i am currently deploying openstack using OSAD and an error is occurring

> Failed to validate the SSL certificate for raw.githubusercontent.com:443. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and not recommended

I have no idea which file i should update with validate_certs=False

Answer (score 1):

This only applies if using a https url as the source of the keys. If set to no, the SSL certificates will not be validated.
This should only set to no used on personally controlled sites using self-signed certificates as it avoids verifying the source site.
Prior to 2.1 the code worked as if this was set to yes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the role for which error appeared, for example for `haproxy_server` SSL error, you should edit a file:

```
/etc/ansible/roles/haproxy_server/defaults/main.yml
```

and set:

```
haproxy_hatop_download_validate_certs: no
```